# How to make router-link work with custom link component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

### `<base-link>` component

I have a Vue component `<base-link>`, which I use every time I want to have an achor. It's mostly for applying styles specific to links, so that all the links across the whole page look the same without applying global styles.

### Make `<router-link>` use `<base-link>`

When using `<router-link>` component to create a link, I cannot apply those styles (`<base-link>` styles are scoped) unless `<router-link>` uses my `<base-link>` component to create the anchor element.

Fortunately `<router-link>` provides [`tag` attribute](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#tag), which seems to do exactly that. Unfortunately I can't get it to work. I have 2 problems:

1. All my components are locally registered (I use ES6 modules with Webpack and import components locally every time I need them). `<router-link>` doesn't know what `<base-link>` component is and can't render it. Is there a way to inject a local component for `<router-link>` to use?
2. To solve problem #1, I thought it's enough to declare `<base-link>` component globally. Unfortunately it still doesn't work. This time `<base-link>` component gets rendered properly, but is still not functional - doesn't react to click events. It seems to me the problem is that it's `href` attribute isn't set at all. Is there a way to make `<router-link>` set it properly? (without setting it manually)

### Question

How do I solve problems #1 and #2? I suspect #1 might be not possible, but I hope at least #2 is.

### Code example

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LrNegb) is a pen with code below, which illustrates both problems.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      component: {
        template: '<p>Homepage template</p>'
      }
    },
    {
      path: "/subpage",
      component: {
        template: '<p>Subpage template</p>'
      }
    }
  ]
});

// Globally registered BaseLink.
Vue.component('BaseLinkGlobal', {
  props: {
    href: String
  },
  template: `
    <a
      :href="href"
      class="BaseLinkGlobal"
    >
      <slot />
    </a>
  `
})

const vue = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  components: {
    // Locally registered BaseLink.
    BaseLinkLocal: {
      props: {
        href: String
      },
      template: `
        <a
          :href="href"
          class="BaseLinkLocal"
        >
          <slot />
        </a>
      `
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <!-- 2 router links. One uses locally registered BaseLink
        -- and the other one a globally registered one. -->
      <nav>
        <router-link
          to="/"
          tag="base-link-local"
        >
          Home
        </router-link>
        <router-link
          to="/subpage"
          tag="base-link-global"
        >
          Subpage
        </router-link>
      </nav>
      <router-view />
    </div>
  `
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a base link component which can double as a normal `a` tag or `<router-link>` when you wish.

```
//Base link

<template>
  <component :is="type" :class="{'base': type === 'a'}" v-bind="$attrs">
    <slot></slot>
  </component>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    routerLink: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    type() {
      return this.routerLink ? 'router-link' : 'a'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scopex>
.base {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
```

## Usage

when you want to use it as a normal link just do not provide the `router-link` prop as below:

```
<base-link>This is a base a tag</base-link>
```

To use it as a `router-link` just add the `router-link` prop along with the `to` prop:

```
<base-link router-link to="/">This is router-link</base-link>
```

Explanation about the base-link component:

- We use a [`component`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#component) which is provided by vuejs to render `a` tag or `router-link` base on the truthiness of the `routerLink` prop.
- A class of `.base` is added if it is a normal link i.e `a`
- we bind [`$attrs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-attrs) which allows us to make the component more transparent i.e allows us to use attributes like `href` or `to` without passing them as props.

  ```
   <base-link href="https://google.com">go to google</base-link>
  ```

You can have a look [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Disabling-Attribute-Inheritance) for more explanation about usage of `$attrs`

Comment: I think that is a very elegant solution, which should get rid of both my problems. I'll just test it and accept it is an answer, if it works.

Comment: I answered this on my tablet so could not provide a working pen... Please test it out and let me know if any problems

Comment: It works, so thank you very much. I still wish simply passing `tag="base-link"` to `<router-link>` would work, as your method might get out of control if there are more (and more complex) third-party components needed to be handled, but in my current situation it's a perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is for solving problem #2

The global component doesn't inherit the event listener of the router link. You can make it inherit by adding `v-on="$listeners"` to the global component.

```
// Globally registered BaseLink.
Vue.component('BaseLinkGlobal', {
  props: {
    href: String
  },
  template: `
    <a
      :href="href"
      class="BaseLinkGlobal"
      v-on="$listeners"
    >
      <slot />
    </a>
  `
})
```

The link works after adding it: https://codepen.io/jacobgoh101/pen/YvqJxL?editors=0010

Comment: Yeah, that should fix the click issues. And do you know how to add `href` attribute to the link to make it a valid anchor?

Comment: unfortunately, router-link doesn't seem to pass the href to the component. So no.